# How to use rollup/cube in pivot table (SUMMARIZE ROWS)

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, rollup

So here is my sample data:

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1319564f72b4b7485b0a30b3aba22555)

and here is my query:

```
select * from (
select
    typ,
    user_name,
    sort,
    count_pc,
    weight    

from stat where typ=1 and dat>=trunc(sysdate)

)
pivot
(SUM(to_number(count_pc)) as pc, SUM(to_number(round(weight,0))) as hm
for sort in ('Alcohol','Food','NotFood' ,'Cigarette' ) )    

order by user_name asc
```

> | TYP | USER_NAME | 'Alcohol'_PC | 'Alcohol'_HM | 'Food'_PC | 'Food'_HM | 'NotFood'_PC | 'NotFood'_HM | 'Cigarette'_PC | 'Cigarette'_HM |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | XX | 24 | 630 | 24 | 630 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |
> | 1 | XY | 64 | 1130 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 38 | 1130 |
> | 1 | XZ | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 128 | 5130 | *null* | *null* |

But I want a **sum_pc**, **sum_weight** at and of the table (one more row- in this case 2). Which user total how many pc and weight has....

DESIRED OUTPUT -- with yellow:

[image]

Comment: it would be good to know what is the desired output.

Comment: @RobertoHernandez Adedd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need to use any `rollup` function. I am quite sure that perhaps there is a better and more elegant solution, but to obtain the output you want you might use this

*Tip: I had to use a subselect in order to get rid off the column names coming out of the pivot.*

```
select 
b.* , 
coalesce(alcohol_pc,0)+coalesce(food_pc,0)+coalesce(notfood_pc,0)+coalesce(cigarette_pc,0) as sum_pc,
coalesce(alcohol_hm,0)+coalesce(food_hm,0)+coalesce(notfood_hm,0)+coalesce(cigarette_hm,0) as sum_hm
from 
(
select typ, 
       user_name,
       "'Alcohol'_PC" as alcohol_pc , 
       "'Alcohol'_HM" as alcohol_hm ,
       "'Food'_PC"    as food_pc ,
       "'Food'_HM"    AS food_hm , 
       "'NotFood'_PC" as notfood_pc ,
       "'NotFood'_HM" as notfood_hm ,
       "'Cigarette'_PC" as cigarette_pc ,
       "'Cigarette'_HM" as cigarette_hm 
from 
(
select
    typ,
    user_name,
    sort,
    count_pc,
    weight
from stat where typ=1 and dat>=trunc(sysdate)
)
pivot
(SUM(to_number(count_pc)) as pc, SUM(to_number(round(weight,0))) as hm
for sort in ('Alcohol','Food','NotFood' ,'Cigarette' ) )
order by user_name asc
) b
```

[image]

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5a5844fe64d3cc1ec2d678a2b4141ec7)